# Detect if SD card is plugged in to iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm writing an iOS application in Swift that needs to detect when a user connects an SD card to the iPhone through a memory card reader. I've had a google around and a look at the Apple Doc and have been unable to find an answer. Does anyone know how to detect programmatically whether an SD Card reader has a card inserted or not?

Is there a similar method such as `mountedVolumeURLs(includingResourceValuesForKeys:options:)`
for iPhone OS?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I guess [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57300140/5928311) or [this doc from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory) - can help you. For correct answer need to check memory card reader with real code implementation